# Odd type error warning when using bs4 to obtain value from website

Tags: python, list, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The following is a snippet from a website, where I am trying to obtain (only) the "Text to Capture". That text is surrounded by a couple of "div" classes, which contain tables, text etc.

```
<div class="rankbox">
    <div>Ranking 
        <div class="tooltip-wrapper"> ... </div>
        <div class="tooltiptext hide"> ... </div>
        **Text to Capture**
        <span class="sr-only"> of 5</span>
        <span class="rank_chip rankrect_1">&nbsp;</span>
        <span class="rank_chip rankrect_2">&nbsp;</span>
        <span class="rank_chip rankrect_3">3</span> 
        <span class="rank_chip rankrect_4">&nbsp;</span>
        <span class="rank_chip rankrect_5">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The oddity here is that the text to capture has no Tags associated to it whatsoever.
I have gotten this to work:

```
rankbox = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'rankbox'})
lx = [x for x in list(rankbox.contents[1])]
returnvalue = str(lx[4]).strip()
```

However, I am getting a type error warning from pycharm:
Expected type 'Iterable[_T]' (matched generic type 'Iterable[_T]'), got 'PageElement' instead
because rankbox.contents[1] is a PageElement, not a List

I am wondering whether there is a more elegant way of doing achieving this , avoiding a warning too

Answer (score 0):

Given this HTML source, the following is the a possible solution that I could think about.

The idea is

1. Get the first `div` tag under `div.rankbox`
2. Remove all `div` and `span` tags
3. Obtain text from the remaining source
4. Remove the text "Ranking" at the beginning
5. Remove surrounding spaces

```py
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="rankbox">
    <div>Ranking 
        <div class="tooltip-wrapper"> ... </div>
        <div class="tooltiptext hide"> ... </div>
        **Text to Capture**
        <span class="sr-only"> of 5</span>
        <span class="rank_chip rankrect_1">&nbsp;</span>
        <span class="rank_chip rankrect_2">&nbsp;</span>
        <span class="rank_chip rankrect_3">3</span> 
        <span class="rank_chip rankrect_4">&nbsp;</span>
        <span class="rank_chip rankrect_5">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

x = soup.select("div.rankbox div")[0]  # div starting with Ranking
# remove all divs and spans
for d in x.find_all("div"):
    d.extract()
for s in x.find_all("span"):
    s.extract()
x = x.text
x = re.sub(r"^Ranking", "", x) # remove "Ranking" at first"
x = x.strip()

x
# '**Text to Capture**'
```

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer helped me to find the shortest code for this:

```
xtract = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'zr_rankbox'})
x = xtract.select('div')[0].find_all(text=True, recursive=False)[1].get_text(strip=True)
```

without type error warning